# Out of Memory error on simple Database calls - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am trying to export a database into a CSV file. PHPmyadmin shows the table is only around 25 MB. I tried bringing down full table exporting to split into 25000 rows each run. (Total is around 60k). Not sure what causes the issue. Its obviously the `fetch_assoc` whats causing this,but not sure why.

```
 if( count($this->input->post()) > 0 ){


        $file = fopen("tmp/export.csv","w");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM  `data` WHERE export=0 LIMIT 2500";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $row = $result->first_row('array');

        //prepare the titles
        $title =array();
        $firstrow = array();
        foreach ($row as $key => $value){
            $title[] = $key;
            $firstrow[] = $value;
        }
        //Write heading titles to the csv
        fputcsv($file,$title);
        fputcsv($file,$firstrow);
        while($row = $result->next_row('array')){
            $buffer = array();
            foreach ($row as $items){
            $buffer[]=$items;
            }
            fputcsv($file,$buffer);
        }

        fclose($file);
```

This is the error I get. 91 bytes?

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 264503296) (tried to allocate 91 bytes) in /var/www/html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php on line 168
```

Any inputs guys?

Comment: In modern versions you have to use [unbuffered queries](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd) to deal with large datasets.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I did to solve the issue after a lot of searching, but I am still not sure why such a small table should cause this memory leak.